# Sorting collection in groovy

Tags: sorting, grails, collections, groovy, gsp

I have code like this in a GSP:

```
<g:each in="${cifUserInstance.cif?.servicePackage?.transactions?.collect{it.service}}" status="i" var="transaction">
```

But the resulting data is not sorted; they are displayed randomly. 
How can I sort the data using the code above?

Comment: How do you want it sorted? What is transactions? What is service? Do you want it sorted by transactions or service? Can you give us an example of how you wish the data sorted?

Comment: I want it sort by service... transaction n service are domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a shot in the dark without seeing what 'transactions' and 'service' look like, but can you try,

```
<g:each in="${cifUserInstance.cif?.servicePackage?.transactions?.service.sort()}" status="i" var="transaction">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<g:each in="${cifUserInstance.cif?.servicePackage?.transactions?.collect{it.service}.sort()}" status="i" var="transaction">
```

BTW, it's better to prepare all data in controller, and use view's gsp only to show result data

Comment: still not working ...
I have made like this before, but didn't work.
Is there any method except collect and also can sorting???

Comment: method `sort()` sorts incoming data, i swear. try harder

Comment: A stupid idea but... are you sure you're object inside the collection are all of the same kind ? It could explain a lot...